# SMTP e-mail dont works, 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail, exchange-server

Morning, I cant understand why this code dont works! thanks, waiting awnsers :)

```
protected void Enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var pass = new NetworkCredential();
        pass.UserName = "myuser@gmail.com";
        pass.Password = "password";


        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.Credentials = pass;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;


        var email = new MailMessage(pass.UserName, "myname@mywork.com.br", txtsubject.Text,
                                    "name   :  " + txtname.Text + "menssage  : " + txtMessage.Text);

        SMTP.Enviar(email);
    }
```

Comment: You spend much time setting up an SmtpClient, then completely fail to use it. What is `SMTP` anyway? Are we meant to guess?

Comment: Also try setting UseDefaultCredentials = false; before Credentials = Pass

Comment: didn't work , I changed the Web.config too, but nothing changed when it runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you need to enable pop3 in your gmail account - Check out Gmail's help section on POP access for Gmail for specific instructions for setting this up with your email program. If you only want to use the SMTP server, skip the POP bits and only set up SMTP to work with your existing email account.

Comment: If you use exchange you probably have to use a different port and you exchange server must support smtp mail sending